# Logic Apps - get OAuth2 token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to get an OAuth2 token from Quickbooks. https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/authentication-and-authorization/oauth-2.0

I've had a good read for an hour but feel no closer to figuring out how to get a token from the OAuth2 service. Does anyone have clear instruction on how to auth (and handle token refresh) in logic apps using OAuth2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the previous Legacy version of Logic Apps there used to be Quickbooks inbuilt Connector but now one of the ways that I found is using Custom Connector.

You can refer to this [tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/quickbooks-api-integration-with-power-automate-using-custom-connectors/) if you have not added Quickbooks Custom Connector.

Note : Make sure that the logic app and the custom connector are in the same region

And now for requesting for retrieving and refreshing access tokens we need to save the APIs in the same collection that we have created and upload it to the custom connector.

Another workaround is to get the access tokens locally in Visual Studio by publishing the same code to azure functions and then add the same azure function connector to our logic apps flow.

REFERENCES:

1. [Retrieve an Access Token - Box Developer Documentation](https://developer.box.com/guides/tooling/postman/access-token/)
2. [c# - Is there a simple way to access the Quickbooks API using OAuth2? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54381095/is-there-a-simple-way-to-access-the-quickbooks-api-using-oauth2)
3. [IvAlex1986/QuickBooks.Net: QuickBooks API wrapper for .NET (github.com)](https://github.com/IvAlex1986/QuickBooks.Net)